# Equivalence of Logistic regression to Gaussian naive bayes

Tags: self-study, logistic, central-limit-theorem, naive-bayes

I was revisiting the differences between logistic regression and Naive Bayes, and had a conceptual question. A logistic regression classifier makes intuitive sense to me as a classifier that directly estimates $P(y \mid x)$ without making any assumptions about how the data is distributed (except that the conditional distribution $P(y \mid x)$ is Bernoulli). To my understanding, however, logistic regression is exactly equal to a Naive Bayes classifier with an assumed Gaussian distribution and constant variance. So, I was wondering, why is it equal if Naive Bayes is making the explicit assumption of a Gaussian distribution?

Thanks.

Comment: Your assertion would benefit from a numerical illustration, as it is not immediately clear what you mean.  The logistic model $p(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-(\beta_0 +\beta_1x))}$ is less Gaussian in nature than the probit model $p(x)= \Phi ( \gamma_0 +\gamma_1x)$ though easier to explain in terms of log-odds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logistic regression assumes a particular functional form for the conditional probabilities $P(c|\mathbf x)$ ($c$ being the class index).

Under the Naive Bayes assumptions with some further restrictions ($x_i|c$  are independent, gaussian distributed with the same variance), the conditional probabilities $P(c|\mathbf x)$ happen to have the same functional form. So you can view Logistic regression as a generalized model, of which this specific instance of Naive Bayes is a special case. Of course this can also viewed as one of the motivations for choosing this particular functional form.